# Quarkus: how to manage complex role relationships?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, quarkus, rbac, microprofile

Our team is currently developing our first Quarkus application, with most developers primarily experienced with the Spring ecosystem. We are facing the following authorization related problem:

Our users are authenticated by openID and JWT using the company-given SSO solution, where some default roles are already given. We have some special domain specific rules like **if user has at least one role of [A, B, C] he implicitely gets role Z** (in principle something like composite roles). The role "Z" is not coming from the JWT token. Authorization in the resource endpoints should then work e.g. with both `@RolesAllowed("A")` and `@RolesAllowed("Z")`.

How would you achieve this in Quarkus?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [`SecurityIdentityAugmentor`](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-security/blob/master/src/main/java/io/quarkus/security/identity/SecurityIdentityAugmentor.java) to modify the `SecurityIdentity`. One that would implement your rule of "if the identity has at least one role of [A, B, C], then it also has role Z" would look like this:

```
@Singleton
public class MyRolesAugmentor implements SecurityIdentityAugmentor {
    @Override
    public int priority() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> augment(SecurityIdentity identity, AuthenticationRequestContext context) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
            QuarkusSecurityIdentity.Builder builder = QuarkusSecurityIdentity.builder(identity);
            if (identity.hasRole("A") || identity.hasRole("B") || identity.hasRole("C")) {
                builder.addRole("Z");
            }
            return builder.build();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly does work. But I was kinda surprised about such a solution. I thought Quarkus was all about using the standard Jakarta EE stuff. This solution seems pretty Quarkus specific. Isn't there something standard?

Also this seems to be such a common use case, do we really need to build this ourself? For example Spring Security has this already built-in.